# iOS UIWebView has a blank page when I add cookies to request

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When I add cookies header to UIWebView request I get a blank page. It loads page well when there are no cookies header in request. When I try this request using curl command it loads the page well.

```
curl --header "Cookie: id=0036100001CWQLFAA5; sn=209caec4cc6d3916186218685c4bea9b1ad4084b; visitor_id290562=124369749; visitor_id290562-hash=262c38ffdae6a7a373cb06ea327cb6bca047b78434f6e15b62f2859c0eab2cd0897a220a4640848783fd8b34008c041eea5adc46" https://ecommerce.thebullbag.com/my-account > Desktop/1.html
```

This is my Swift code:

```
let url = URL(string: WebSiteUrl + "/my-account")!
            let webController = TOWebViewController(url: url)!
            webController.urlRequest.addValue("Cookie", forHTTPHeaderField: "id=0036100001CWQLFAA5; sn=209caec4cc6d3916186218685c4bea9b1ad4084b; visitor_id290562=124369749; visitor_id290562-hash=" +
                    "262c38ffdae6a7a373cb06ea327cb6bca047b78434f6e15b62f2859c0eab2cd0897a220a4640848783fd8b34008c041eea5adc46")
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: webController)
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

When I remove `webController.urlRequest.addValue` page is loaded well.

I added everything into Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ecommerce.thebullbag.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo:

```
webController.urlRequest.addValue("id=0036100001CWQLFAA5; sn=209caec4cc6d3916186218685c4bea9b1ad4084b; visitor_id290562=124369749; visitor_id290562-hash=" +
                    "262c38ffdae6a7a373cb06ea327cb6bca047b78434f6e15b62f2859c0eab2cd0897a220a4640848783fd8b34008c041eea5adc46",
                    forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
```